# Playwright browser launch function is not working on Heroku

Tags: python, web-scraping, heroku, playwright, playwright-python

My code:

```
def check_xyz_status(user_input):
    
        
    user_input_list = user_input.split(',', maxsplit=1)
    if len(user_input_list) != 2:
        return f"Input is incorrect! Please type your username (email address) followed by a comma (,) and password. Example: yourname@email.com,MyPa55word)"
    elif user_input_list[0] == "":
        return f"Input is incorrect! Please type your username (email address) followed by a comma (,) and password. Example: yourname@email.com,MyPa55word)"
    elif user_input_list[1] == "":
        return f"Input is incorrect! Please type your username (email address) followed by a comma (,) and password. Example: yourname@email.com,MyPa55word)"

    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True,channel="chrome",executablePath='/app/vendor/chrome/bin/chrome') 
        #
        print(browser)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto('SITE_URL',timeout=300000) #,timeout=100000
        page.fill('input#UserName',user_input_list[0].strip())
        page.fill('input#Password',user_input_list[1].strip())
        page.click('input[type=submit]')
        try:
            page.goto('SITE_URL/PAGE',timeout=300000) #,timeout=500000
            page.is_visible('div.k-grid-content k-auto-scrollable')
            html = page.inner_html('#elmnt')
        except:
            return 'Incorrect username(email) or password.'
                
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
        tds = soup.find_all('td')
        status_list = [] 
        for td in tds:
            status_list.append(td.text)
        if len(status_list) == 0:
            return 'Server is busy, try again later :)'
        else:
            return f'Your application\'s status is {status_list[3]}({status_list[5]} for {status_list[6]}), submitted on {status_list[4]}'
```

This works as expected on the local machine(obviously). When I deploy it in Heroku the web browser part does not return anything. The purposes is to login to a website and fetch some data. User input validation parts written in the code are working(because it has nothing to do the browser object).

Here is the issue:

```
browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
```

I did some search and found the Heroku does not have browser to perform the actions written in my code. Based on some suggestion I have updated my buildpacks with the following,

```
https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
https://github.com/minted/heroku-buildpack-chrome-headless
```

But no luck. I even changed aforementioned code and not working.

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True,channel="chrome",executablePath='/app/vendor/chrome/bin/chrome')
```

I am naive in web scraping. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Playwright implicitly has browsers, you don't need to give the route of the browser. It is not like selenium which needs route to browser or have it installed. Try to put just this line     browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True). Maybe when you run it first time it will download all browsers. Also you are using BeautifulSoup why? You have PW selectors https://playwright.dev/python/docs/selectors

Comment: @MeT Well, `browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)` this was my initial code, but it did not work, that's why I explicitly assigned a browser path.  Is there anything else that I am missing? And **Thanks** for PW selectors.

Comment: Then you run it first time PW needs to download some packages, browsers .... Maybe heroku blocks some ports. Try to put all the packages in heroku by yourself. Also do you know exactly where is the problem? Do you have log of error if yes post the error? Try to put more log traces.

Comment: @MeT There is no error while deploying the app. I ran playwright install after the deployment to make sure all dependencies are installed